# how to fix the gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

this is my first flask app deployment

this my directory tree

```
/home/goku--
            |_ __pycache__
            |_ virbubble
            |_ flaskapp.py
            |_ wsgi.py
```

this is the `flaskapp.py`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

this is the `wsgi.py`

```
from flaskapp import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I created the `goku` and added into `nginx` group

this is the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/flaskapp.conf`

```
server {
listen 5000;
server_name 'my IP';
location =/favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
root /home/goku;
}
location / {
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $ remote-addr;
proxy_set_header Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_pass http://unix:/home/goku/flaskapp.sock
}
}
```

and this is the `/etc/systemd/system/flaskapp.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=goku
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/goku
Environment=”PATH=/home/goku/virbubble/bin”
ExecStart= /home/goku/virbubble/bin/gunicorn -access-logfile - --workers 3 -bind unix:/home/goku/flaskapp.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

when I run `[root@localhost ~]# sudo systemctl status flaskapp` I got this :

```
flaskapp.service - gunicorn daemon
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/flaskapp.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-03-06 13:05:05 UTC; 8min ago
    <br/>Main PID: 27830 (code=exited, status=2)
    <br/>Mar 06 13:05:05 localhost systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
    <br/>Mar 06 13:05:05 localhost gunicorn[27830]: usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
    <br/>Mar 06 13:05:05 localhost gunicorn[27830]: gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: -access-logfile unix:/home/goku/flaskapp.sock wsgi:app
    <br/>Mar 06 13:05:05 localhost systemd[1]: flaskapp.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
    <br/>Mar 06 13:05:05 localhost systemd[1]: Unit flaskapp.service entered failed state.
    <br/>Mar 06 13:05:05 localhost systemd[1]: flaskapp.service failed.
    <br/>Mar 06 13:05:09 localhost systemd[1]: [114B blob data]
```

and I don't have `flaskapp.sock` file

how can I fix this

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
-access-logfile -
```

to

```
--access-logfile -
```